# Select Without Special Character In Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this value in my MySQL table, for example: `100%`, but I want to `SELECT` those values without the 1%1 character. I try to do something like 1REPLACE1 but still failed. Anyone can give any solution?

Comment: Any reason you can't post-process the string in your client app to remove it? String transformations aren't really what sql databases are intended for.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a zero to convert string to number, e.g. -

```
SELECT '100%' + 0;
+------------+
| '100%' + 0 |
+------------+
|        100 |
+------------+
```

In your case write something like this -

```
SELECT column_name + 0 AS column_name FROM table_name;
```

Comment: thank you so much...i try it and it works to select one column. But how to select more than one column?

Comment: SELECT column1 + 0, column2, column3 and so on

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT REPLACE(col, '\%', '') AS col
```